# Key prop exists on list item but still getting key warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen all flavors of this issue and yet I can't seem to figure out what on earth is going wrong. I do not extract out my list items, I am just displaying a UL and I gave a unique key to each list item. When I console log out results, I get something like:

```
0:
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
    key: "85110d30-0a52-4b95-bae2-e98a8a7e4e2c"
```

In my parent component:

```
<Route path='/projects/'>
    { isLoading ? (
        <div>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
    ) : (
        [
            <ProjectList projects={this.state.userProjects} />,
            <CreateProject handler={this.handleNewProject} user={user} />
        ]
    )}
```

In ProjectList component:

```
const results = props.projects.map( (result) =>
    <li key={result.MembershipId}>
        <Link to={ `${match.url}/${result.ProjectId}` }>{result.ProjectName}</Link>
    </li>
);

return (

    <React.Fragment>
        <h2>My Projects</h2>
        { results.length ? (
            <ul>{results}</ul>
        ) : (
            <p>You are not part of any projects yet. You can create one!</p>
        )}
        
    </React.Fragment>
    
);
```

the li is the outermost element if I understand correctly. The ID is not undefined. Yet I still keep getting key warnings. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you show the exact text of the warning?

Comment: Can you confirm there is no duplicate `MembershipId` &  undefined values

Comment: There is no duplicates, at the moment there's only two items and their IDs are different.

Comment: The warning says `index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this due to the fact you are returning an array as children in the route without adding keys?

[image]

Comment: Fascinating! Yes... you are right, that triggers the warning. Guess I didn't think of that array like that. Thank you.